# Python creating md5 hashes from a list or text

Tags: python, md5, hashlib

when it's a string in the script it generates it correctly like:

```
result = hashlib.md5(b"12345")
print(result.hexdigest())
```

this is: 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b as it should be but when it comes to read a word from a list or a text it doesnt give the correct md5 hash. I tried to strip "\n" but it didnt work. What should i do? What would you do if you were to generate md5 hashes from a text?

```
import hashlib

result = hashlib.md5()

with open("text.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        line.strip("\n")

        result.update(line.encode())
        result_md5 = result.hexdigest()


        print(result.hexdigest())
```

output is: 4528e6a7bb9341c36c425faf40ef32c3

b6cef2a8d7cd668164035a08af6eab17

f44b0df2bb9752914ceac919ae4ca5e5

text file:

```
pass
12345
password
```

expected output is:

```
1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72
827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b
5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
```

Comment: Show sample code, sample text file, result and expected result as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I tried to do it. I hope now it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an MD5 hash independently for each line.

```
import hashlib

with open("text.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip("\r\n")
        result = hashlib.md5(line.encode())
        print(result.hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import hashlib

with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    temp = f.read().splitlines()
    for each_element in temp:
        result = hashlib.md5(each_element.encode("utf-8"))
        print(result.hexdigest())
```

> Output

```
1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72
827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b
5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move this:

```
result = hashlib.md5()
```

inside your loop, so it's reinitialized every time for every new line. The final code might look like this:

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(hashlib.md5(line.strip().encode()).hexdigest())
```

Comment: Getting `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`